# Looking for a CalDAV Tasks (aka To-Do List) Android app

Tags: android, synchronization, todo

My network includes a CalDAV calendar hosted on [Baïkal](https://sabre.io/baikal/). It allows me to share a calendar between my desktop (Linux and Thunderbird) and my Android phone running [OneCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.codespark.xcalendarapp). The devices sync automatically when they are both connected on my home network.

Baïkal and Thunderbird both support tasks, but OneCalendar does not. I would like to add this functionality to my phone (a Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android version 12), so I am seeking a CalDAV to-do app for Android; or a combined calendar and task manager.

This question on Android Enthusiasts, [How do I manage CalDAV-provided tasks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42355/how-do-i-manage-caldav-provided-tasks) seems to be a duplicate, but the accepted answer OpenTasks will not install for me.

I have read lots of product descriptions and reviews, but it is rare to see CalDAV mentioned. Many boast about Google Calendar, but I prefer to keep my data under my control and will not use a cloud solution.

I have tried these:

- OpenTasks, but it requires an old version of Android
- DAVx⁵ could not connect to my server. It said: “This app is for organisations and not for private users.”
- Syncthing-Fork only seems to sync with other Syncthing installations.

Before I waste lots of time trying other apps where the description is incomplete, I would like to hear from anyone who has experience of CalDAV tasks.

Please let me know of any useful knowledge in this area.

Comment: I use DAVx⁵ with my Nextcloud for years and have never seen that error message. Where did you install it from? They have 2 different versions, one for organizations ("Managed DAVx⁵") and one for "private users" – maybe you've picked the wrong one? The one I use is [this one from F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/at.bitfire.davdroid/), which is [also available at PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.davdroid).

Comment: @Izzy The F-Droid versions seem better. I now have DAVx⁵ working. I'm not there yet, but your comment is a big help. Please rewrite your comment as an answer, ideally with suggestion(s) for a tasks app (I am looking at jtx Board).

Comment: I most exclusively use my apps from F-Droid (disclosure: I'm also one of the maintainers there) – & I can say your statement holds true for some other apps as well ;) But while I could write a recommendation for DAVx⁵, I don't use any tasks app & thus could not include that. Though once sync'd to your device, I guess all task apps (as long as they use Android's calendar storage) should pick them up. You can find [a selection on my website](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo) to pick from. [Tasks.org](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.tasks/) seems to fit.

Comment: Actually, reading the description and checking the screenshots of [Tasks.org](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.tasks/), it seems it can sync with CalDAV on its own even, so maybe take a look at that first (while I update that to its description at above linked app listing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Izzy for the suggestions in Comments.

I installed DAVx⁵ from F-Droid (this version is free, unlike the Play Store version). It was easy to create an account linking to my Baïkal server.

DAVx⁵ had a couple of suggestions for the task app. I chose jtx Board which seems to work well. It’s more feature-rich than I anticipated, but I’m sure I will use the other features.

Comment: I've just discovered that i can 'Share' an SMS with jtx Board. After a sync, it appears in Thunderbird as a Task.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I *really* have to recommend **Singularity** on the android playstore. It has that and more. Projects, habits, tasks, calendar -all incorporated together however you choose. It's my dream-come-true app. I don't, but my brain hates **all** other task, calendar, journal, habit, and project apps for some reasom *besides ***Notify*** for notes]*. All other apps seem to consistently not be up to my liking / standards or work for me.

The only thing I would change in the Singularity app would be switching the checklist and note section in *Projects*, but that's just Projects fortunately. Otherwise, I absolutely adore it.

Hopefully I didn't misundetstand your post about it simply needing to have a calendar feature *[not one that syncs specifically with one the one you already have -though it might, or they might implement it for you since they're new and very customer oriented]*. It syncs with Google calendar, but I think I remember there being another calendar option, for "*other calendars*" .

Oddly, the app also syncs with telegram and email, as to create a telegram message or email to 'quickly create a task'. Personally, I'll just be using the app to do that. I haven't used a task app in years until this one. There's also a website for it to in case that matters.

Hope you find it as helpful as I have! Or, eventually find one that's as helpful as **Singularity** has been for me!
Sorry about the anonymous answer. Im having an issue logging in.

Comment: Not sure what to make of this answer. It's like a cross between an ad and a rant. There's not even a link to the app. The only `Singularity` I could find seems to be something else. If you wish to be taken seriously, please remove the gushing and the reference to Google (as per OP, it is out-of-scope), and add some references.